# Can not convert "int" to "System.Func < Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Jtoken,bool>

Tags: c#, json

I have problems to use the .Count Methode in C# JToken. Anyone know what I made wrong?

I get an error in this row:

```
JToken lastid = (int)IDObject["data"].Count(-1)["q_id"];



Argument "2": Can not convert "int" to "System.Func
<
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Jtoken,bool>"
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, I have 567 Ids in a json Format. With .First I can get the Id = 1 and now I want get the last Id, in this case it is the id = 567

Comment: you say JToken = (int)anything. you are trying to make a jtoken an int (not sure if thats a real problem tho because I don't know JToken, if its normal ignore my comment)

Comment: What is your purpose? .`Count` returns `int`.

Comment: I have 567 Ids. And I want to Count them -1 down

Comment: You want to return the last JToken in the list, or the id of the last JToken in the list?

Comment: I want to return the id of the last JToken in the list so the number 567

Comment: `Count` returns an `int` containing the number of elements in the collection.  `Count()` does not accept an `int` value as a parameter, so `Count(1-)` is not a valid statement.

Comment: Edit your question to include what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to return the ID of the token at the bottom of the list.

The usage of .Count() is incorrect, see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx). The function itself will return the sum of elements inside the list. Alternatively you could pass it a Function which will return the count of all the elements in the list that fulfill the requirement. The error you're receiving is because Count(-1) is expecting a function, but got an int instead.

Now to retrieve the ID of the last token in the list. You could simply call the last item of the list with

```
int id = IDObject["data"].Last()["q_id"];
```

[.Last()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775(v=vs.110).aspx) will call the last item in the list.

For additional information on Lists and how to navigate them I suggest checking out the [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) or [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/list) handy site

EDIT:

Most likely you're JSON is something like

```
{ "data":[{
       "question1", 
       "question2", 
       "question3"
       }]
}
```

Calling IDOBject["data"] turns these questions into a

```
{
   "q_id", 
   "q_text", 
   "q_something_else", 
   "q_id", 
   "q_text", 
   "ect.."
}
```

A future advice would be to ommit the data you send with an additional tag. So something like

```
{"data": 
    **question**:[
     {
        "q_id", 
        "q_text", 
        "q_something_else"
     },{
        "q_id", 
        "q_text", 
        "q_something_else"
     }]
 };
```

This would help keeping your questions seperated from eachother.
But it's only an advice because I do believe that there is an solution for your current problem.

```
int id = IDObject["data"].Where(tag => tag.Equals("q_id")).Last()["q_id"];
```

The where will filter out all the tags besides the "q_id" tag. Assuming thr 567 is the last q_id, .Last() will select this tag.

Edit 2:

Actually you might even be able to short it by simply getting the relevant tag that you want, 567.

```
int id = IDObject["data"].Where(tag => tag["q_id"] == 567);
```

or in case of a string

```
int id = IDObject["data"].Where(tag => tag["q_id"].Equals("567"));
```

Comment: I tried this before but it gets be the output lastQuestionId = 9

So my json is looks {"q_id":"567","q_text":"Die meisten Ehepaare zeigen nicht viel Zuneigung für einander."},{"lastQuestionId":"9"}],"tag":"question","error":null}

Comment: IDObject["data"].Last()["q_id"]; that gives as output lastQuestionId = 9? and a JToken data looks like this: {[{"q_id":"567","q_text":"Die meisten Ehepaare zeigen nicht viel Zuneigung für einander."},{"lastQuestionId":"9"}],"tag":"question","error"‌​:null}?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm going to guess you have a big chunk of JSON data. And all your ["data"] is in a big array. Calling .First() will get you the first item, in your case that be "q_id", but calling last would grab "lastQuestionId:9". I think I understand, lemme see if I can patch something up for you

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible to pass the Count method an int as parameter. At that point the error probably gets thrown, because you get quite a similiar error when trying to execute the following code:

```
new List<int>().Count(-1);
//Argument type 'int' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Func<int,bool>'
```

Maybe you could help by clarifying what exactly you're trying to do.